# Adblock Plus: Write rules matching links?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, adblock

I have a site that has a banner. The banner comes from the own site to circumvent Adblocks, so you can't just block the image tag otherwise all images of that site wouldn't be displayed. The image tag however is in an a-tag pointing to doublecklick. So I want to block any a-tags that links to doubleclick, even if I can't reach doublecklick at all then. How is that possible?

I tried

```
##a[href="*.doubleclick.net/*"]
```

but that doesn't work, the element is still displayed. Are wildcards allowed in quote marks at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard cannot be within the attribute text you want to match, it must instead be specified next to the equal sign, e.g. the following should work:

```
##a[href*="doubleclick.net/"]
```

There are some other match operators that can be applied to attributes in a similar way, e.g. `^=` for starts-with and `$=` for ends-with.